# How to incorporate real time variable into an equation for swift 3.0

Tags: swift, function, time

I am trying to create a function to tell the distance traveled after the elapse of x amount of actual clock time.

Would like to incorporate real time into this function: So after x amount of time of traveling, will still be able to obtain distance traveled in real time.

So: let distanceTraveled = (rate * realClockTimeTraveled)

I just don't know how to incorporate actual clock time into the equation.  I would appreciate your insights and suggestions.  Thank you so much, in advance!

Comment: Have a look at timeIntevalSinceDate or just NSDate https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsdate/1417376-timeintervalsincereferencedate

Comment: Thank you for your reply, AMAN77!  I will definitely research on the reference that you gave.